# Application get close when i write getwriteable database for store data in Sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to store data in Sqlite database. I created a helper class which extends Sqlite openhelper class.
I wrote all the code to create database table and columns.
I call `savedata` method when clicked on save button in my **MainActivity**. 
Problem occured when I wrote code for getwriteable database.
App did not response and closed.

```
public class ClientDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     EditText client_name, client_address, client_mobile_number, client_email_id, policy_name, policy_number;
     Button save, edit, delete;
     ListView listView;
     SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
     Context context;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_details);

         client_name = findViewById(R.id.client_name);
         client_address = findViewById(R.id.client_address);
         client_mobile_number = findViewById(R.id.client_mobile_number);
         client_email_id = findViewById(R.id.client_email_id);
         policy_name = findViewById(R.id.et_policy_name);
         policy_number = findViewById(R.id.et_policy_number);
         save = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
         edit = findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
         delete = findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
         listView = findViewById(R.id.list);




     }

     public void Savedata(View view) {
        Helper helper=new Helper(context);
        helper.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
         values.put(Helper.COL_CLIENT_NAME,client_name.getText().toString());
         values.put(Helper.COL_CLIENT_ADDRESS,client_address.getText().toString());
         values.put(Helper.COL_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER,client_mobile_number.getText().toString());
         values.put(Helper.COL_CLIENT_EMAIL_ID,client_mobile_number.getText().toString());
         values.put(Helper.COL_POLICY_NAME,policy_name.getText().toString());
         values.put(Helper.COL_POLICY_NUMBER,policy_number.getText().toString());

        String clientname=client_name.getText().toString();
        if(clientname.equals("")) {
            long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(Helper.CLIENT_TABLE,null,values);

            Toast.makeText(context,"ID"+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
     }
 }
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at com.example.smartagent.ClientDetailsActivity$override.Savedata(ClientDetailsActivity.java:46)
        at com.example.smartagent.ClientDetailsActivity$override.access$dispatch(ClientDetailsActivity.java)
        at com.example.smartagent.ClientDetailsActivity.Savedata(ClientDetailsActivity.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10482 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the Context being passed is null. You either need the variable context to be in scope within the onClickListener or as below get the Context from the view that was clicked via the getContext() method.

You also need the variable sqLiteDatabase to be a valid SQLiteDatabase object and hence the second line that assigns the SQLiteDatabase retrieved via the helper instance of the Helper object as instantiated in the previous line.

try changing

```
Helper helper=new Helper(context);
helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

in the **Savedata** method to

```
Helper helper=new Helper(view.getContext());
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```